# Detect user arrived to a location and depart from a location pattern using CMMotionManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, machine-learning, core-motion

I am working on app which requires to detect user arrived to place and depart from a place and time spent in that location. 
I am reading CoreMotion Readings but unable to get any clue how to form patterns.

```
if (_motionManager == nil) {
    _motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc]init];
}
_motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1/60;
[_motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        [_motionManager stopDeviceMotionUpdates];
        NSLog(@"Error while reading accelerometer data: %@", error.description);
        return;
       }
      [self getacceleration:motion];
}];
```

In `filterMotionData` I am trying to read device acceleration with `motion.userAcceleration` but not find any good solution.

```
- (void)getacceleration:(CMMotion*)motion {
    CMAcceleration acceleration = motion.userAcceleration;
   //Calculate Device acceleration
}
```

Here If I can calculate device acceleration then on slowing down device acceleration I can say user arrived to a Location and when as device acceleration increased for particular time period means user depart from a location.

I was exploring I came to know **Moves** app does the same for all version of devices.

I gone through CLVisit API provided by CLLocationManager but it won't give short stay of user in a location and also its notify very late.

Please guide if anyone work on same type of requirement.